# Removing shadow under shell action bar Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble finding a solution for this and even the attribute stated on the documentation site is not working. This is the sample in the documentation:

```
<ContentPage ...
             Shell.NavBarHasShadow="true">
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

When I try to add the attribute to my ContentPage it returns an error that says

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error XLS0415 The attachable property 'HasShadow' was not found in
>   type 'Shell'. LoanApp2    LoanHistory.xaml    8

This my MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoanApp2.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="LoanApp2.MainPage" BackgroundColor="#62bef0" Title="Dylan Villaruel">

    <FlyoutItem Title="MyTabApp" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Loan History" IsTabStop="True" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoanHistory}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Amount Loanable" IsTabStop="True" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:AmountLoanable}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

The ShellContent are both wrapped by ContentPage as root tags.

[This is a screenshot of the issue:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJEfO.png)

Comment: I can add for Shell.NavBarHasShadow="true" in Shell project, please check your Xamarin.Forms version, my version is 4.4.0.991265

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT how do I check Xamarin.Forms version? It don't see Xamarin.Forms on my about page just the other Xamarin and Xamarin.*

Comment: Never mind, you don't actually see the version in the about section in the visual studio. You had to check on the nuget package manager. Mine says version 4.3

Answer (score 1):

You can add Shell.SetNavBarHasShadow(this, false) in codebehind of your page. For example:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class HomeView : ContentPage
{
    public HomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Shell.SetNavBarHasShadow(this, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@e700867

You need to create custom renderer to remove shadow from navigation in shell, hope below code will help you :

```
public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public CustomShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker CreateToolbarAppearanceTracker()
    {
        return new CustomShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(this);
    }
}

internal class CustomShellToolbarAppearanceTracker : IShellToolbarAppearanceTracker
{
    private CustomShellRenderer customShellRenderer;

    public CustomShellToolbarAppearanceTracker(CustomShellRenderer customShellRenderer)
    {
        this.customShellRenderer = customShellRenderer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public void ResetAppearance(Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker)
    {

    }

    public void SetAppearance(Toolbar toolbar, IShellToolbarTracker toolbarTracker, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {

        toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
        var viewParent = (Android.Support.Design.Widget.AppBarLayout)toolbar.Parent;            
        viewParent.SetElevation(0.0f);
    }
}
```

Thanks